# Fastest way to find common events in 2 time series numpy arrays and calulate synchronisation statistic

Tags: python, numpy

1. Given 2 numpy arrays `a1` and `a2` (composed only of 0 and 1's), find index locations of all 0's in `a1` and `a2`.
2. Find matching index positions if any between array `a1` and `a2`.
3. Calculate a metric.

`a1` array shape is 2161
`a2` array shape is 2161

e.g.

```
a1 = [0,1,1,0,1,0,1]
a2 = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
```

The indices of all 0's in `a1` are 0, 3, and 5.
The indices of all 0's in `a2` are 2, 3, and 6.

The only common index between `a1` and `a2` is thus 3.

`function_1` performs step1 and step2 and step3

`function1_iterations` repeats `function_1` after randomly shuffling `a1` and repeating metric calculation 1000 times. This is for the purpose of finding if metric is statistically significant.

I perform below code on 100 million array pairs, multiprocessed on 256 cores. Best runtime for 100 million array pairs is about 40 mins. Is there any way I can make it significantly efficient? I need to be running this on billions of array pairs.

My code below is the fastest that I could come up with some help from people from codereview earlier:

```py
    def function_1(self, a1, a2):
            event_index1, = np.where(a1 == 0)
            event_index2, = np.where(a2 == 0)
            n1, = event_index1.shape
            n2, = event_index2.shape
        
            if n1 == 0 or n2 == 0:
                return 0, 0
        
            n_matches, = np.intersect1d(event_index1, event_index2, assume_unique=True,).shape
            
            c_ij = c_ji = n_matches/2
     
            metric_1= (c_ij + c_ji) / math.sqrt(n1 * n2)
       
            return metric_1

        
        def function1_iterations(self,a1,a2,repeat = 1000,original_metric1):
            list_metric1 = []
            a1_copy = copy.deepcopy(a1)
            
            for i in range(0, repeat):
                np.random.shuffle(a1_copy)    # shuffle bits in array and recalculate 1000 times  
                
                metric_1 = self.function_1(a1= a1_copy, a2 = a2) 
                list_metric1.append(metric_1)
            list_metric1= np.array(list_metric1)
          
            significance_val = len(np.where(list_metric1>= [original_metric1])[0])/repeat
            
            return significance_val
```

Comment: https://tio.run/##fVJNb4MwDL3nV/g0hQ1RyLRLJfYTetodBXBFqiXQELZ1h/115vAxWsTqSwJ@79nPTnNxVW2e@17pprYOTKebC8gWTMOmX05pVG7@0tJVjJV4hGPCZRKCFMGewRT4gcZlypT4RamUVKLPCi0SEtIU4mALKW6RYoU0g9K1ctRWssEFIFYAsQKoI4kMqlBbgg/XpWkfFl1nDcQhxItuRmaLCtupP2Uc2hYLl5T81uitGdm2ncasM@rcYfpmOwyDVUdFpk4kWmQn5bXnQjvxh9DorCqyJAU@gJ8GcAC7YQNRe7aOk6lHsrOManIxc6c9ias9@Tl4L0XdUcemNt9oa/4jExLxg9nK@QJG/8N7GPNTZYJtNsjYgfhJ7IPJUcpKU9Z6OPghgFeIoxeW38mxxtIKuH93IeSB36L35u/BnBwfazQe/F3qvJR7mCmhf9852pQ6Ic5ditii9P0v this is a lot faster (~100x)

Comment: @rak1507 I checked your code snippet. But it does something completely different. Instead of finding the indexes of 0's it counts how many nonzero elements exist in array.

Comment: it returns the same result, so it is functionally identical

Comment: @rak1507 Sorry but the results are emtirely different. Maybe for some cases it was same for you due to chance. Logic is completely different too. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: @skynaive can you provide an example where the results are different? yes the logic is different, that's to speed it up

Comment: @rak1507 Lets take a1 = 2161 array with 2 zeros at index [957,958], a2 with 2161 elements with 0's at indexes [1434,1435,1629]. My code will gives result for this as 0, because no zeros between a1 and a2 are found at a common index location. Your code gives 0.99

Comment: @skynaive my code gives 0 as well https://tio.run/##hZJNboMwEIX3PoVXFbQowc5Pm0rcojsUIQMT4ajYxDZt00WvTgdiSoNS1QsLj795njdDc3aVVquuk3WjjaOqrZszFZaqhviQkzVIN55q4SpCSjjQAwsEi6jg4TOhfsEbKJdJVcIHXiWosnivwACSNEloHN4i@TXJZ6QalH4rL2wlGpgAPgP4DJAHFBlUqTaID59T0f0y4FqjaBzReNLN0GxRgfX1SeXAWCgcK4Nro9dmhLVtDVmr5KmF5MW0EIWziopMHlG0yI6y1x4fWvIfogZnZJGxhAYD/DDAIV0OE1jYk3EBmrpHO1OrvIsx18@J/5pT34feS6FbrFhp9QlGB1@CoUjfmFt3/QOq/iPv7nLvX0bsZoFEXNK1AhtwtsV6SnduIMFYrvVrSPL/ACLSdLd5jHabp/0e4ZjkacrWq3WE2yZiW77z8cbgpIL@94xoHobjmftz130D

Comment: @rak1507 Your code needs to be copied from that `run` into an answer, and this comment thread needs to continue on that answer and not on the question.

Comment: @Reinderien The above original code belongs to your answer actually a few months back. Thanks

Comment: @rak1507 I am not sure why your code gives me a wrong result on my machine. Could it be related to int32, 64 representations?. For eg. ~a1 is supposed to invert bits. I was expecting it to turn 1's to 0 and viceversa, but it returns 2's complement of array on my machine

Comment: Your code will not interpret. The syntax for `original_metric` is incorrect. Please show your working code, and also please show expected results of both function calls given your sample `a1` and `a2`.

Comment: Also, this appears to be a method on a class due to the `self`. Please show the entire class.

Comment: Note that @rak1507 's solution is only equivalent in results to the OP's if the input dtypes are `bool`. Otherwise, bitwise operations will produce different results.

Comment: Thanks @Reinderien for pointing that out and for turning it into a full answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring your `function1_iterations`: `function_1` should call neither `where` nor `intersect1d`. Your metric expression numerator just evaluates to `n_matches`. A faster vectorised approach will be, either in the integer or boolean domain, perform the equivalent of `sum(!a1 & !a2)`:

```
import math
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np


def function_1_old(a1, a2):
    event_index1, = np.where(a1 == 0)
    event_index2, = np.where(a2 == 0)
    n1, = event_index1.shape
    n2, = event_index2.shape

    if n1 == 0 or n2 == 0:
        return 0, 0

    n_matches, = np.intersect1d(event_index1, event_index2, assume_unique=True, ).shape

    c_ij = c_ji = n_matches / 2

    metric_1 = (c_ij + c_ji) / math.sqrt(n1 * n2)

    return metric_1


def function_1_arith(a1: np.ndarray, a2: np.ndarray) -> float:
    zeros1 = 1 - a1
    zeros2 = 1 - a2
    n1 = np.sum(zeros1)
    n2 = np.sum(zeros2)
    if n1 == 0 or n2 == 0:
        return 0

    n_matches = np.sum(zeros1 * zeros2)
    return n_matches / np.sqrt(n1 * n2)


def function_1_bool(a1: np.ndarray, a2: np.ndarray) -> float:
    zeros1 = np.logical_not(a1)
    zeros2 = np.logical_not(a2)
    n1 = np.sum(zeros1)
    n2 = np.sum(zeros2)
    if n1 == 0 or n2 == 0:
        return 0

    n_matches = np.sum(np.logical_and(zeros1, zeros2))
    return n_matches / np.sqrt(n1 * n2)


def function_1_demorgan(a1: np.ndarray, a2: np.ndarray) -> float:
    n1 = a1.size - np.sum(a1)
    n2 = a2.size - np.sum(a2)
    if n1 == 0 or n2 == 0:
        return 0

    n_matches = np.sum(np.logical_not(np.logical_or(a1, a2)))
    return n_matches / np.sqrt(n1 * n2)


def function_1_count(a1: np.ndarray, a2: np.ndarray) -> float:
    n1 = a1.size - np.count_nonzero(a1)
    n2 = a2.size - np.count_nonzero(a2)
    if n1 == 0 or n2 == 0:
        return 0

    n_matches = np.count_nonzero(np.logical_not(np.logical_or(a1, a2)))
    return n_matches / np.sqrt(n1 * n2)


def function_1_binary(a1: np.ndarray, a2: np.ndarray) -> float:
    n1 = a1.size - np.count_nonzero(a1)
    n2 = a2.size - np.count_nonzero(a2)
    if n1 == 0 or n2 == 0:
        return 0

    n_matches = np.count_nonzero(~(a1 | a2))
    return n_matches / np.sqrt(n1 * n2)


def test() -> None:
    methods = (function_1_old, function_1_arith, function_1_bool, function_1_demorgan, function_1_count,
               function_1_binary)
    a1 = np.array((0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), dtype=bool)
    a2 = np.array((1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), dtype=bool)

    # Testing against expected results, with OP's original sample arrays
    for method in methods:
        assert np.isclose(1/3, method(a1, a2), rtol=0, atol=1e-12)

    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)  # for reproducible results

    def sample():
        return rand.integers(low=0, high=2, size=(10_000,), dtype=bool)
    a1, a2 = sample(), sample()

    # Test for regression with bigger sample arrays
    reference = None
    for method in methods:
        result = method(a1, a2)
        if method is function_1_old:
            reference = result
        else:
            assert np.isclose(reference, result, rtol=0, atol=1e-12)

    # Performance measurement with those arrays
    n = 1_000
    for method in methods:
        dur = timeit(lambda: method(a1, a2), number=n)
        print(f'{method.__name__}: {dur/n*1e6:.1f} us')

'''
function_1_old: 386.6 us
function_1_arith: 54.8 us
function_1_bool: 44.2 us
function_1_demorgan: 43.1 us
function_1_count: 6.9 us
function_1_binary: 6.7 us
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Thanks for this comparison. I went ahead with the binary bool array version. I was wondering how to approach such efficiency problems in the future? Like to know binary version is much faster than the one I was using naively.

Comment: A mix of knowledge (full-matrix vectorisation is generally faster than indexing) and guessing (are bitwise operators faster than boolean operators?) backed up by measurement. Always, always measure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% confident that I understand your intent, but looking at your code it seems like all we care about is the number of zeroes in each list and the number of times those zeroes line up by index. The actual indexes themselves dont seem to matter.

I found that just ignoring the arrays, and treating the whole thing as a simple list problem, was more than twice as fast.

```
def function_1_new(a1, a2):
    n_matches = 0
    n_zeroes_a1 = 0
    n_zeroes_a2 =0

    for sub_a1, sub_a2 in zip(a1, a2):
        if sub_a1 == sub_a2 == 0:
            n_matches += 1
            n_zeroes_a1 += 1
            n_zeroes_a2 += 1
        else:
            if sub_a1 == 0:
                n_zeroes_a1 += 1
            if sub_a2 == 0:
                n_zeroes_a2 += 1

    c_ij = c_ji = n_matches/2
    metric_1= (c_ij + c_ji) / math.sqrt(n_zeroes_a1 * n_zeroes_a2)
    return metric_1
```

Running your original function 1,000,000 times took me 26.5 seconds on average. The more naïve approach above averaged around 11 seconds. And here's how I tested to make sure the new code produces the same results as the old code.

```
def function1_iterations_sameness(a1,a2, original_metric1, repeat = 1000000):
    a1_copy = copy.deepcopy(a1)
    for i in range(0, repeat):
        np.random.shuffle(a1_copy)    # shuffle bits in array and recalculate 1000 times  
        metric_1_old = function_1(a1= a1_copy, a2 = a2) 
        metric_1_new = function_1_new(a1_copy, a2)
        assert metric_1_old == metric_1_new
```

Comment: This implementation is logically correct but in terms of performance it's a disaster. I encourage you to revisit your performance check. Where the fastest method I evaluated completes in 7.8 microseconds, yours took almost four thousand times (!) as long.